# \textbullet in CMU Serif font family looks very large

Tags: fontspec

In order to use `\scshape` and `\bfseries` together within the cm-related fonts, I switch my main font to the font family CMU Serif. However, `\textbullet` in the CMU Serif font family looks very large.

my MEW is (using xelatex):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\f@encoding

\f@family

\f@size

\rmdefault

\sfdefault

\ttdefault

\makeatother

\textbullet

\end{document}
```

If I comment `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}`, `\textbullet` will look normal. So what's wrong with my MWE?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, the font simply has a rather large bullet. Btw: you don't need to load textcomp.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, thanks for your answer. How can I change the "normal" one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bullet in CMU Serif is big.

You can use `newunicodechar` to select a different font for •:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\LM}{Latin Modern Roman}

\newunicodechar{•}{{\LM•}}

\begin{document}

\textbullet\ {\LM\textbullet} •

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep using `\textbullet`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\LM}{Latin Modern Roman}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\textbullet}{}{{\LM\symbol{`\•}}}
\newunicodechar{•}{{\LM•}}

\begin{document}

\textbullet\ •

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer~